# Adding an image to title slide using slidify

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidify

I am using the latest version of Rstudio (and knitr) and I have installed the development version of slidify from github. Slidify allows you to go straight from Rmarkdown to html5slides with 1 click.

My issue is that I would like to add an image to the title slide, but using the normal Rmarkdown syntax does not work.  I think this is because the first slide is specified as a YAML.

```
title       : 
subtitle    : 
author      : 
job         : 
framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
```

If I add anything to this first slide specification, I get an error in the function yaml.load() which parses the YAML.  Is there a way to specify a background image using YAML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The title-slide in `io2012` framework is marked with the class `title-slide`. So you can customize the slide using css. For example, if you want to specify a background image, you need to add the following css.

```
  .title-slide {
     background-image: url(http://goo.gl/cF6W2);
   }
```

You can either add it directly to your Rmd file by enclosing it with `<style></style>` tags or to a custom css file in `assets/css`, which will automatically be included when you run `slidify`.

Hope this is useful.

EDIT. If you want to customize the appearance of the title slide further, you can tweak the lines in [libraries/frameworks/io2012/layouts/deck.html](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidifyLibraries/blob/master/inst/libraries/frameworks/io2012/layouts/deck.html#L25-L48).

Comment: Thanks Ramnath.  What an awesome package! What's the best resource for slidify documentation at this point?

Comment: At this point, it would be http://slidify.org, but I plan to document more extensively. For questions, the best place would be SO or the issues page on github.