# Custom background in title-slide using quarto's reveal implementation

Tags: pandoc, reveal.js, quarto

I'm using quarto's reveal.js implementation. I've been reading the [official documentation page on customising themes](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/themes.html) and I'm relatively familiar with SCSS rules.

I've been able to create classes to slides and then customise them via SCSS rules. Regretfully, I haven't been able to add a custom background (either colour or, ideally, image background) to the first slide (`#title-slide`) covering the entire area, as I would do in other regular slides as described [here](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#slide-backgrounds).

Is there any way to add custom backgrounds to the first slide other than [this hack consisting of leaving the presentation's attributes blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777699/adding-title-slide-image-to-rmarkdown-slides-with-reveal-js)?

EDIT:

Not sure if that's the right approach, but I tried adding the background-image url in the yaml metadata and it works:

```yaml
---
title: "My title"
background-image: "https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1580139624070-910f651c1b78?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
background-opacity: "0.45"
format: 
  revealjs:
    theme: [default]
    logo: images/logo_black.png
editor: visual
---
```

Regretfully, properties such as `background-color` and `background-opacity` don't work.

Comment: Using `background-image` is a good approach. It is [documented](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#on-all-slides-beamer-reveal.js-pptx) in the pandoc manual that (mostly) applies to quarto as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me that! Following the document I made it work and I managed to apply other properties, too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for the record, after [@tarleb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884987/custom-background-in-title-slide-using-quartos-reveal-implementation/72893626#comment128737886_72884987) pointing me to [pandoc's documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#on-all-slides-beamer-reveal.js-pptx), I made it work by adding this on yaml's metada:

```yaml
---
[...]
title-slide-attributes:
    data-background-image: "/path/to/image"
    data-background-size: contain
    data-background-opacity: "number"
[...]
---
```

As can be seen, other attributes can be passed, as long as

1. they are indented under `title-slide-attributes`
2. they are prepended with `data-`

Comment: PS: added a PR with this info so this can be added to quarto's official documentation: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-web/pull/251